# count and fetch each number individually and count how many times each number appears in a database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the problem I am having.

My table has as column MSISDN, i want to count fetch each number individually and count how many times each number appears
then display it in a table the particular number and the number of time it occurs, such as

```
Number(MSISDN) | No of times
```

Here is my code, i am stocked as i dont know what step to take or how to move from where i am.

```
$go=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request_from");
$go2=mysql_fetch_array($go);

$i=0;
while($go2=mysql_fetch_array($go))
{
$i++;

$tel=$go2['msisdn'];

//counting number of time each number occurs
$xtt=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request_from WHERE msisdn='$tel'");

$xtt2=mysql_fetch_array($xtt);

$g=1;
while($xtt2=mysql_fetch_array($xtt))
{
   $g++;
}
echo $tel occurs $g times; //for all the phone numbers, it displays the number of time each number occurs
```

Comment: Please post full code..

Comment: Is count fetch a verb?

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
SELECT msisdn ,sum(1) anz FROM request_from
GROUP BY msisdn;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's much simpler to do this in sql:

```
SELECT msisdn, COUNT(*) AS number_of_occurrances FROM request_from GROUP BY msisdn;
```